# wrapper class(How to convert an array of primitives to an array of wrappers

Tags: java

> Create a class WrapperDemo that includes a function convert2ObjAndStore that convertsan integer into an Integer object and stores the Integer object in a Vector object namedintVector.Store “n” such converted objects in intVector.Iterate the vector and receive theobject as an integer value and display it.Also include a function that swaps one Integerobject with the other and display the swapped value in the calling routine (main function enclosed in a class named WrapperMain)

I tried this but i am getting an error for converting the interger to Integer object

```
import java.util.*;

class WrapperDemo {

    static void Convert(Integer []ob,int n) {

        Vector<Integer> store=new Vector<Integer>();

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            store.add(ob[i]);
            System.out.println(store.get(i));
        }
    } 
}

class WrapperMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();

        int[] x=new int [20];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            x[i]=sc.nextInt();
            WrapperDemo.Convert(x,n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: *i am getting an error*: then read the error message to know what is wrong and where.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your error is that you declare `x` as `int[]` but pass it to a method that is expecting `Integer[]`. This will not be autoboxed!

EDIT : To make it clearer ...

```
class WrapperDemo {

static void Convert(Integer []ob,int n) { // <-- type Integer[]
```

versus

```
int[] x=new int [20]; // <-- type int[] which is NOT equal to Integer[] 
                      //     and will NOT be autoboxed to Integer[]
// ...
WrapperDemo.Convert(x,n); // You give type int[] to a method that is expecting Integer[]
```

And as a side-note:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        x[i]=sc.nextInt();
        WrapperDemo.Convert(x,n); // <- You call the convertion in each iteration.
    }
```

You call the convertion in each iteration of the filling loop. So most of the entries will be null. You might want to change that to:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        x[i]=sc.nextInt();
}
WrapperDemo.Convert(x,n);
```

Comment: i have declared Interger as 'Integer[]' ob only

Comment: Yes, but you call it with `x` which is of type `int[]`.

Comment: U mean to say that in formal parameters i Write 'int[] ob' instead of 'Integer[] ob'???